# Library libldap not loaded

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I use Macbook and install php with brew and ohmyzsh. But now i cant run `php` syntax in my terminal.

The return error is

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
[1]    65451 abort      php
```

I have already run `brew install openldap libiconv` syntax to reinstall the library, but its not working now.

If i run `which php` its return `/usr/local/bin/php`.

Thank before.